# Missing python kernel in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am new to jupyter/ipython. I usually start the notebook on a remote machine and create a ssh tunnel. Details of how the tunnel is set up can be found here: http://www.hydro.washington.edu/~jhamman/hydro-logic/blog/2013/10/04/pybook-remote/

However, many times when I start a notebook, it reports back with 0 active kernels (not all the times). Following is the screenshot of that:

```
-bash-4.1$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=7777
[NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /x/y/z
[NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:7777/
[NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

I obviously have python.

```
python --version
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)
```

Can someone explain to me this erratic behavior? and how it can be fixed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Attached is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong here. You won't have a running Python kernel until you actually open a notebook file.

Comment: On opening a browser, it would say missing kernel and crash.

Comment: Can you show what errors you get in the browser and in the terminal when you try to open or create a notebook?

Comment: @ThomasK I have added a screenshot of the error I get on opening an existing notebook.

Comment: Is there anything in the dropdown list? Do you have the package `ipykernel` installed?

Answer (score 0):

I also use jupyter using a ssh tunnel and was getting `0` active kernels message and I could not run any notebook. My error snapshot is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039349/no-python-terminal-in-jupyter-notebook).  The ipython kernel was not installed properly in the direct install of jupyter using `sudo -H pip install jupyter`. I resolved it by updating the ipython kernel using:

1. `sudo apt-get -y install ipython ipython-notebook`
2. `sudo -H pip install jupyter`

If it doesn't work, try uninstalling jupyter and then install packages in sequence as explained in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04) link.