# No python terminal in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]
Attached a screenshot of the error. I have tried creating python 3 and python2 virtualEnv but nothing is working. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest using `conda env` instead of virtualenv for best compatible since anaconda is the team behind `jupyter`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating the ipython kernel. I could not run any notebook because it was showing `0` active kernel message in the command prompt and hence I couldn't run any python kernel in the browser. Following steps solved the problem:

1. `sudo apt-get -y install ipython ipython-notebook`
2. `sudo -H pip install jupyter`

Following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04) link solved the problem.